# set size of div based on floating element inside

Tags: html, css

I am building a small html web page.
In my web page I've got a div, inside it I've got a floating div.
I'd like to get the height of my wrapper div to be similar to that of my floating div.
How can this be done in css \ html?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I'm guessing the problem is that your containing `div` looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkHa4/ - it's not extending to the `height` of the `float`ed `div`.

The solution is to ["clear your floats"](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

An easy way to do this is to apply `overflow: hidden` to your containing `div`, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkHa4/1/

Comment: thank you very much. I am not completely sure what overflow has to do with this though.

Comment: See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910075/why-overflow-hidden-clears-a-float) and then [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work/6199172#6199172).

Answer (score 2):

Thirtydot is correct, you should clear your floats, but I would recommend you use the clearfix method instead. Using `overflow:hidden` will cause unintended problems with CSS properties that extend past the boundaries of a container.

[CSS overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078684/css-overflow-issue/6079067#6079067)

Comment: I tend to use `overflow: hidden` in the vast majority of cases, and only fall back to using `clearfix` when I must. A (minor) downside to `clearfix` is that you must stick a less than semantic `class="clearfix"` all over your HTML. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I used `overflow: hidden` as well. Check out http://fordinteractive.com/2009/12/goodbye-overflow-clearing-hack/. As CSS3 becomes more common, clearfix will not cause the issues overflow does. Simply makes it more future compatible.